# Return closest element in GeoSeries

Tags: performance, geopandas

Is there any built-in function or quick hack to efficiently return the closest element (index) to a point for a given geopandas GeoSeries?

Something like

```
>> geopandas.GeoSeries(
>>     {
>>         0:Point(1,1),
>>         1:Point(3,2),
>>         2:Point(2,3),
>>     }
>> ).closest_element(Point(0.99,0.99))
>  0
```

I could calculate the distance to every single element and return the sorted list index's first element, but this solution is really slow and I feel like there should be some better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions

```py
pts = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(2,3),Point(3,2),Point(1,1)])
distances = [ (i, pt.distance(Point(0.99,0.99)))  for i, pt in enumerate(pts)]
print distance
[(0, 2.2494888308235717), (1, 2.2494888308235717), (2, 0.014142135623730963)]
print min(distance,key=lambda item:item[1])
(2, 0.014142135623730963)
```

or

```py
from operator import itemgetter
print min(distance,key=itemgetter(1)) 
(2, 0.014142135623730963)
```

and

```
print pts[2]
POINT (1 1)
```

But GeoPandas uses [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) which has the function [nearest_points](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/docs/manual.rst#id89)

Whith Shapely

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint
pts = MultiPoint([Point(2,3),Point(3,2),Point(1,1)])
pt = Point(0.99,0.99)
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
[o.wkt for o in nearest_points(pt, pts)]
['POINT (0.99 0.99)', 'POINT (1 1)']
```

With GeoPandas

```py
pts = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(2,3),Point(3,2),Point(1,1)])
pts =  pts.unary_union # convert to Shapely MultiPoint geometry
pt = Point(0.99,0.99)
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
[o.wkt for o in nearest_points(pt, pts)]
['POINT (0.99 0.99)', 'POINT (1 1)']
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these approaches ran quicker than my current implementation (described in the original question). The nearest_points approach looked promising, but I still had to find which index corresponded to the point, which increased run time significantly. Thanks for the tips.